# Saving String[] as a single String in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to take my 4 String arrays and convert them in to a single string separated by a ",". It seems to save the information easy enough when I debug; however, when I try and getString - it doesn't retrieve the data. I'm trying to determine why:

```
    String[] debtName = new String[10];
    String[] debtAmount = new String[10];
    String[] debtRate = new String[10];
    String[] debtPayment = new String[10];

    //Load Data

    SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("chaosdatasnowball", 0);
    debtName = sharedPref.getString("debtNames", null).split(",");

    //End Load

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int flipper = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<debtName.length;i++)
    {
        if(debtName[i].equals(null) && !extras.equals(null) && flipper!=1)
        {

            debtName[i] = extras.getString("newDebtName");
            debtAmount[i] = extras.getString("newDebtAmount");
            debtRate[i] = extras.getString("newDebtRate");
            debtPayment[i] = extras.getString("newDebtPayment");
            flipper = 1;
        }
    }
```

..............

```
    StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder("");
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();

    for (String i : debtName) {
        value.append(i + ",");
    }
    editor.putString("debtNames", value.toString());

    for (String i : debtAmount) {
        value.append(i + ",");
    }
    editor.putString("debtAmounts", value.toString());

    for (String i : debtRate) {
        value.append(i + ",");
    }
    editor.putString("debtRates", value.toString());

    for (String i : debtPayment) {
        value.append(i + ",");
    }
    editor.putString("debtPayments", value.toString());

    editor.commit();
```

Correction, when run outside of debug, this gives a nullpointer exception on:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("chaosdatasnowball", 0);
        debtName = sharedPref.getString("debtNames", null).split(",");  <---this line
```

Here is where the activity is called:

```
    EditText editDebtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtName);
    debtName = editDebtName.getText().toString();

    EditText editDebtAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtAmount);
    String debtAmountStr = editDebtAmount.getText().toString();

    EditText editDebtRate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtRate);
    String debtRateStr = editDebtRate.getText().toString();

    EditText editDebtPayment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dispDebtPayment);
    String debtPaymentStr = editDebtPayment.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(this, DebtList.class);
    i.putExtra("newDebtName", debtName);
    i.putExtra("newDebtAmount", debtAmountStr);
    i.putExtra("newDebtRate", debtRateStr);
    i.putExtra("newDebtPayment", debtPaymentStr);

    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: _"it doesn't retrieve the data"_ how do you know? Does it crash? What output do you see?

Comment: So what means doesn't retrieve data?

Comment: Post the output of **debtName.**

Comment: when I debug, it won't show a value for it when I do it this way.. if I change the getString to getString(debtNames, "debtNames") it outputs "debtNames"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have surrendered to the apparent fact that there is no valid way to do this so I have hard coded 40 variables in to the app now. If anyone comes up with anything useful, please feel free to post it and I'll check this every so often.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```
debtName = sharedPref.getString("debtNames", null).split(",");
```

It is possible that the key `debtNames` does not exist. Therefor null is returned.

This will happen when you run the app for the first time and have not saved anything to the shared preference yet.

Add a check for null and handle this case. Something like, if null is returned, then show default values, else show values that are read from sharedpreference.

Comment: Why? Are you sure to save the values to shared preference before this method is called? I don't see the flow of your code..